# How to Create Neumorphism Style Button in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience

I'm interested in creating a 
[Neumorphism Style Button](https://dribbble.com/shots/9990053-Neumorphic-button-animation). This design utilizes two shadows for the button to create the effect as noted in this image

[image: this image].

I'm wondering how one would go about adding two shadows to a button. I'm aware of using elevation, but that only adds one shadow and I can't seem to find a way to add two like in the second link.

Cheers

Comment: You have to create a custom view and add customization to it.

Comment: You can implementand understand this by below link: https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism

Comment: neumorphism is all about contrast and shaddow